# iPad Video Playback only delivers audio, not visuals

Tags: iphone, video, audio, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

Recently we've developed an iPhone app for an external company, and everything works fine in the app.

There is a section where the app pulls video from the client's server, and streams it into the iPhone's MPMoviePlayerController. This works *fine* on the iPhone and iPodTouch - both the video and the audio show up just great.

The problem, however, is that when the app is run on an iPad (using the iPad's iPhone simulator thingo that it does) only the audio plays, and no video can be seen.

Does anybody have any suggestions about what may be causing this? I thought perhaps it was the encoding, but then why would this prevent the video from playing on the iPad, and not the iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mpmovieplayerviewcontroller instead, you might find it works better.Here is a link to the ref  http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/iPad/index.html#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller_class/reference/reference.html